# Display the user which is not friend of logged in user sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, friend

I have tow SQL table with name **ACCOUNTS** and **FRIENDS** and

---

- $member['id'] **means id of users**
- $client['id'] **means id of user that is logged in**

---

**I want to display the user which is not friend of logged in user**
I try this code but this give SQL error the code is

```
$isfriend = sql_counts(sql_query("SELECT * FROM `".tb()."friends` WHERE uid={$member['id']} and fid={$client['id']}"));
$res = sql_query("select * from `".tb()."accounts` where !isfriend order by DESC limit 30");
```

Comment: What is the SQL error? `where !isfriend` is probably where it is choking. Not sure what you are trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

it's probably because sql_query nor sql_counts function is defined.

You should use

mysql_num_rows() and mysql_query()

*Sure this answer applies only if they are not your own functions